# Apache Commons Configuration - PropertiesConfiguration closed

Tags: java, io, properties-file

`PropertiesConfiguration.java` doesn't have a `close()` method. Is there something else that needs to be done to release the file? I want to be sure before I use this in production. I've looked through the code and I don't see anything. I'm not entirely sure how `PropertiesConfiguration.setProperty()` is working without opening a connection to the file that would then have to be closed.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: There's no `PropertiesConfiguration` class in the JRE. If you're getting it from somewhere else, you need to explain.

Comment: I would assume he's talking about the `PropertiesConfiguration` class from Apache Commons Configuration. This question cannot be answered definitively without knowing how you used the 'load' method, but as a general rule of thumb, if you open a resource, _you_ need to close it. If a library used by literally thousands opens it, you can rest assured that it is being cleaned up properly.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been specific about where the class came from.

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone would down vote a question, unless they are just a miserable a**hole. Very few jobs seem to gather as many self-important, smug douchebags as Software Development. Editing a question, though, makes sense, so thank you @Charuක.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  `org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration` the input (stream, path, url, etc...) is of course closed when the properties were loaded in the `PropertiesConfiguration` instance.

You could have the confirmation in the `void load(URL url)` method of `org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration`.

Here is how this method is called :

1) `PropertiesConfiguration` constructor is invoked :

```
public PropertiesConfiguration(File file) throws ConfigurationException
```

2) which calls its super constructor :

```
public AbstractFileConfiguration(File file) throws ConfigurationException
{
    this();

    // set the file and update the url, the base path and the file name
    setFile(file);

    // load the file
    if (file.exists())
    {
        load(); // method which interest you
    }
}
```

3) which calls `load()` :

```
public void load() throws ConfigurationException
{
    if (sourceURL != null)
    {
        load(sourceURL);
    }
    else
    {
        load(getFileName());
    }
}
```

4) which calls `load(String fileName)`:

```
public void load(String fileName) throws ConfigurationException
{
    try
    {
        URL url = ConfigurationUtils.locate(this.fileSystem, basePath, fileName);

        if (url == null)
        {
            throw new ConfigurationException("Cannot locate configuration source " + fileName);
        }
        load(url);
    }
    catch (ConfigurationException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new ConfigurationException("Unable to load the configuration file " + fileName, e);
    }
}
```

5) which calls `load(URL url)`

```
public void load(URL url) throws ConfigurationException
{
    if (sourceURL == null)
    {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(getBasePath()))
        {
            // ensure that we have a valid base path
            setBasePath(url.toString());
        }
        sourceURL = url;
    }

    InputStream in = null;

    try
    {
        in = fileSystem.getInputStream(url);
        load(in);
    }
    catch (ConfigurationException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new ConfigurationException("Unable to load the configuration from the URL " + url, e);
    }
    finally
    {
        // close the input stream
        try
        {
            if (in != null)
            {
                in.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            getLogger().warn("Could not close input stream", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the `finally` statement, you can see that the inputstream is closed in any case.

Comment: Thanks @davidxxx. I think I wasn't trusting what I was seeing.